# How to test a function which include an async function?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

there is a function

```
function foo(){
  bar('hi',callback)
}
```

`bar` is an async function, how to test `foo` in mocha or other test frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
describe('', function() {
  it('', async function() {
    const result = await foo();
    result.should.equal('hi');
  });
});
```

Mocha supports async await now.
refer the link https://mochajs.org/

Answer (score 0):

For this function you can simply return a value.
Now based on callback type either you can stub a promise:

```
 bar.returns('some value', Q.reject({success: false}))
```

Or maybe a function:

```
bar.returns('some value', sinon.spy())
```

P.S I haven't tested this. 
You might wanna read:

http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.0.0/spies/

http://sinonjs.org/